# Linearise product of two integer variables for MILP

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

First up I'm new to this sort of task so please bare with me. I'm trying to linearise (for use in a MILP written in GAMS) the following constraint:

$$ f_{h,n} \le \beta_{n} x_{h,n} \sum_{n} C_n x_{h,n}  $$

with:

$$ 0 \le x_{h,n} \le 100 $$
$$ 0 \le f_{h,n} $$

where $x_{h,n}$ is an integer variable and $\beta_n$ and $C_n$ are constant by $n$. One option I've been investigating is to binary expand $x_{h,n}$ as:

$$ x_{h,n} = \sum_{k=0}^7 2^k m_{h,n,k} $$

where $m_{h,n,k}$ is a binary variable and then make use of the ability to linearise the product of two binaries (see e.g. [this link](https://www.leandro-coelho.com/linearization-product-variables/)). However, I'm getting a bit lost how to write the usual constraints:

$$ z_{h,n} \le m_{h,n,k} $$
$$ z_{h,n} \le m_{h,k} $$
$$ z_{h,n} \ge m_{h,n,k} + m_{h,k} - 1 $$

Does this still work ok given the nested summation? And could anyone please assist with the formulation (in GAMS if at all possible but no worries if not).

Many thanks

Comment: Your first inequality is expressed incorrectly. $n$ can either index the variable being constrained ($f_{h,n}$) or be the index of summation, but not both. Fixing this will make the question clearer.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess that might be the problem and where I'm getting lost because, for each $h$ I do want to sum $x_{h,n}$ across $n$ and then multiply by $x_{h,n}$. Are you saying it isn't possible to express that in a MILP?